# django aggregate for multiple days

Tags: django, database, performance, aggregate

I have a model which has two attributes: date and length and others which are not relevant. And I need to display list of sums of length for each day in template.

The solution I've used so far is looping day by day and creating list of sums using aggregations like:

```
for day in month:
    sums.append(MyModel.objects.filter(date=date).aggregate(Sum('length')))
```

But it seems very ineffective to me because of the number of db lookups. Isn't there a better way to do this? Like caching everything and then filter it without touching the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.values()` can be used to group by `date`, so you will only get *unique* dates together with the sum of `length` fields via `.annotate()`:

```
>>> from django.db.models import Sum
>>> MyModel.objects.values('date').annotate(total_length=Sum('length'))
```

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values):

> When **.values()** clause is used to constrain the columns that are returned in the result set, the method for evaluating annotations is slightly different. Instead of returning an annotated result for each result in the original QuerySet, the original results are grouped according to the unique combinations of the fields specified in the **.values()** clause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Can I group it by foreign key of foreign key of this model? I tried to do `values('first_fk__second_fk')` but it remains split by the `first_fk`.